# can I join to all rows in a reference table as a kind of template?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

I am working on an app that has some scheduling functionality. As part of this, I need to select a list of people and whether or not they have have something scheduled in a certain period of the week.

The number of periods in the week are variable so they are stored in a reference table, for example:

```
Period Reference Table

id   name       start                 end                     day
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Morning    1900-01-01 4:00:00    1900-01-01 11:00:00     MON
2    Afternoon  1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 20:00:00     MON  
3    Night      1900-01-01 20:00:00   1900-01-01 24:00:00     MON  
4    Morning    1900-01-01 4:00:00    1900-01-01 11:00:00     TUE
5    Afternoon  1900-01-01 14:00:00   1900-01-01 20:00:00     TUE  
6    Night      1900-01-01 20:00:00   1900-01-01 24:00:00     TUE
```

I also have a "person reference" table and a "person schedule" table.
The "person schedule" table only stores a record if a person has something scheduled in a period, here is a simplified example:

```
Person Schedule Table

id    person_id     period_id
------------------------------
1     1             2
2     1             3
3     2             2
4     2             3
5     2             4
```

Now I need to select from these three tables a full list of periods for each person and whether they have a schedule record in the period or not (1 or 0). In other words, I need to get this resultset for the example data above:

```
person_id     period_id     is_scheduled
----------------------------------------
1             1             0
1             2             1
1             3             1
1             4             0
1             5             0
1             6             0
2             1             0
2             2             1
2             3             1
2             4             1
2             5             0
2             6             0
```

Is it possible to do this with a select statement without getting into dynamic SQL?

This is all done using SQL Server 2000

Comment: I think you meant to have a 1 under `is_scheduled` for person_id = 2, period_id = 4, no?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh yes sry, that's a 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  people.person_id, period_id = periods.id, is_scheduled = CASE
  WHEN schedule.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.[period reference table] AS periods
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT person_id 
    FROM dbo.[person schedule table] 
    GROUP BY person_id
) AS people
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  dbo.[person schedule table] AS schedule
  ON people.person_id = schedule.person_id
  AND periods.id = schedule.period_id
ORDER BY 
  people.person_id, p.id;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I was working over different joins for 45 mins.